# Difference between dict.clear() and assigning {} in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, is there a difference between calling `clear()` and assigning `{}` to a dictionary? If yes, what is it?
Example:

```
d = {"stuff":"things"}
d.clear()   #this way
d = {}      #vs this way
```

Comment: I wonder if this makes a difference on the garbage collection part. I feel like .clear() should be nicer to the memory system.

Answer (score 317, accepted):

If you have another variable also referring to the same dictionary, there is a big difference:

```
>>> d = {"stuff": "things"}
>>> d2 = d
>>> d = {}
>>> d2
{'stuff': 'things'}
>>> d = {"stuff": "things"}
>>> d2 = d
>>> d.clear()
>>> d2
{}
```

This is because assigning `d = {}` creates a new, empty dictionary and assigns it to the `d` variable. This leaves `d2` pointing at the old dictionary with items still in it. However, `d.clear()` clears the same dictionary that `d` and `d2` both point at.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I still have to get used to the mindset that = creates references in python...

Comment: = copies references to names. There are no variables in python, only objects and names.

Comment: While your "no variables" statement is pedantically true, it's not really helpful here. As long as the Python language documentation still talks about "variables", I'm still going to use the term: http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: I found tzot's comment helpful in adjusting my thinking about names, variables, and types of copies. Calling it pedantic may be your opinion, but I find it to be an unfairly harsh judgement.

Comment: Also clear() do not destroy the removed object in the dict which may still be referenced by someone else.

Comment: @LorenzoBelli A deep clear is imo overly destructive in most situations, but a simple recursive function should do the job in that scenario.

Answer (score 33):

`d = {}` will create a new instance for `d` but all other references will still point to the old contents. 
`d.clear()` will reset the contents, but all references to the same instance will still be correct.

Answer (score 22):

In addition to the differences mentioned in other answers, there also is a speed difference.  d = {} is over twice as fast:

```
python -m timeit -s "d = {}" "for i in xrange(500000): d.clear()"
10 loops, best of 3: 127 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "d = {}" "for i in xrange(500000): d = {}"
10 loops, best of 3: 53.6 msec per loop
```

Comment: This isn't really a valid speed test for all cases since the dict is empty. I think making a large dict (or at least some content) would yield a much smaller performance difference...plus I suspect the garbage collector might add a little of its own hurt to d = {} (?)

Comment: @Rafe : I think the point is if we know that no other variable is pointing to dictionary d, then setting `d = {}` should be faster as cleaning up whole can be left to Garbage Collector for later.

Answer (score 9):

As an illustration for the things already mentioned before:

```
>>> a = {1:2}
>>> id(a)
3073677212L
>>> a.clear()
>>> id(a)
3073677212L
>>> a = {}
>>> id(a)
3073675716L
```

Comment: This shows that `.clear` modifies the object but ` = {}` creates a new object.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to @odano 's answer, it seems using `d.clear()` is faster if you would like to clear the dict for many times.

```
import timeit

p1 = ''' 
d = {}
for i in xrange(1000):
    d[i] = i * i
for j in xrange(100):
    d = {}
    for i in xrange(1000):
        d[i] = i * i
'''

p2 = ''' 
d = {}
for i in xrange(1000):
    d[i] = i * i
for j in xrange(100):
    d.clear()
    for i in xrange(1000):
        d[i] = i * i
'''

print timeit.timeit(p1, number=1000)
print timeit.timeit(p2, number=1000)
```

The result is:

```
20.0367929935
19.6444659233
```

Comment: I'm not sure the difference is significative. Anyways, on my machine, the results are opposite!

Answer (score 7):

*Mutating* methods are always useful if the original object is not in scope:

```
def fun(d):
    d.clear()
    d["b"] = 2

d={"a": 2}
fun(d)
d          # {'b': 2}
```

Re-assigning the dictionary would create a new object and wouldn't modify the original one.

Answer (score 4):

One thing not mentioned is scoping issues. Not a great example, but here's the case where I ran into the problem:

```
def conf_decorator(dec):
    """Enables behavior like this:
        @threaded
        def f(): ...

        or

        @threaded(thread=KThread)
        def f(): ...

        (assuming threaded is wrapped with this function.)
        Sends any accumulated kwargs to threaded.
        """
    c_kwargs = {}
    @wraps(dec)
    def wrapped(f=None, **kwargs):
        if f:
            r = dec(f, **c_kwargs)
            c_kwargs = {}
            return r
        else:
            c_kwargs.update(kwargs) #<- UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c_kwargs' referenced before assignment
            return wrapped
    return wrapped
```

The solution is to replace `c_kwargs = {}` with `c_kwargs.clear()`

If someone thinks up a more practical example, feel free to edit this post.

Comment: `global c_kwargs` would probably also work no? Although probably `global` isn't the best thing to be using a lot of.

Comment: @fantabolous using `global` would make the function behave differently - all calls to conf_decorator would then share the same c_kwargs variable. I believe Python 3 added the `nonlocal` keyword to address this issue, and that would work.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, sometimes the dict instance might be a subclass of dict (`defaultdict` for example). In that case, using `clear` is preferred, as we don't have to remember the exact type of the dict, and also avoid duplicate code (coupling the clearing line with the initialization line).

```
x = defaultdict(list)
x[1].append(2)
...
x.clear() # instead of the longer x = defaultdict(list)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. That's an interesting piece of information.