# Alter elements of a list

Tags: python, coding-style

I have a list of booleans where occasionally I reset them all to false. After first writing the reset as:

```
for b in bool_list:
    b = False
```

I found it doesn't work. I spent a moment scratching my head, then remembered that of course it won't work since I'm only changing a reference to the bool, not its value. So I rewrote as:

```
for i in xrange(len(bool_list)):
    bool_list[i] = False
```

and everything works fine. But I found myself asking, "Is that really the most pythonic way to alter all elements of a list?" Are there other ways that manage to be either more efficient or clearer?

Comment: This isn't really terribly Pythonic.  What's so precious about a list of booleans that you can't reconstruct it?  Could you provide a little more context around this?

Comment: There's nothing prohibiting reconstructing the list in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
bool_list[:] = [False] * len(bool_list)
```

or

```
bool_list[:] = [False for item in bool_list]
```

Comment: Chosen because this style's effect is clear, doesn't suffer from the limitation that there be only one reference to the list, and the performance for the top one is superb.

Answer (score 13):

If you only have one reference to the list, the following may be easier:

```
bool_list = [False] * len(bool_list)
```

This creates a new list populated with `False` elements.

See my answer to [Python dictionary clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/369898/python-dictionary-clear#369925) for a similar example.

Comment: Voted down because he's indicated that he needs it to act in an existing list.

Comment: Voted up because "existing list" can easily be replaced with new list via assignment statement.

Comment: Also if you want to change the existing list you can change it to bool_list[:] = [False] * len(bool_list)

Comment: If this is a very large list, this code might be bad since you're essentially making two copies of the list.  But it should work in about 95% of all situations.

Answer (score 13):

Here's another version:

```
bool_list = [False for item in bool_list]
```

Answer (score 12):

**Summary**
Performance-wise, numpy or a list multiplication are clear winners, as they are 10-20x faster than other approaches.

I did some performance testing on the various options proposed. I used Python 2.5.2, on Linux (Ubuntu 8.10), with a 1.5 Ghz Pentium M.

**Original:**

```
python timeit.py -s 'bool_list = [True] * 1000' 'for x in xrange(len(bool_list)): bool_list[x] = False'
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 280 usec per loop

**Slice-based replacement with a list comprehension:**

```
python timeit.py -s 'bool_list = [True] * 1000' 'bool_list[:] = [False for element in bool_list]'
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 215 usec per loop

**Slice-based replacement with a generator comprehension:**

```
python timeit.py -s 'bool_list = [True] * 1000' 'bool_list[:] = (False for element in bool_list)'
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 265 usec per loop

**Enumerate**:

```
python timeit.py -s 'bool_list = [True] * 1000' 'for i, v in enumerate(bool_list): bool_list[i] = False'
```

1000 loops, best of 3: 385 usec per loop

**Numpy**:

```
python timeit.py -s 'import numpy' -s 'bool_list = numpy.zeros((1000,), dtype=numpy.bool)' 'bool_list[:] = False'
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 15.9 usec per loop

**Slice-based replacement with list multiplication:**

```
python timeit.py -s 'bool_list = [True] * 1000' 'bool_list[:] = [False] * len(bool_list)'
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 23.3 usec per loop

**Reference replacement with list multiplication**

```
 python timeit.py -s 'bool_list = [True] * 1000' 'bool_list = [False] * len(bool_list)'
```

10000 loops, best of 3: 11.3 usec per loop

Comment: I'm glad I timed them. Up until now, I had thought that list multiplications were neat, but probably slow.

Comment: That's a good summary! You should mark this as the answer. I had no idea numpy was THAT much faster. Dang

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use [numpy](https://numpy.org/) arrays, it's actually really easy to do things like this using array slices.

```
import numpy

bool_list = numpy.zeros((100,), dtype=numpy.bool)

# do something interesting with bool_list as if it were a normal list

bool_list[:] = False
# all elements have been reset to False now
```

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use the range and len. It's a lot cleaner to use enumerate()

```
for i, v in enumerate(bool_list): #i, v = index and value
    bool_list[i] = False
```

It's left with an unused variable in this case, but it still looks cleaner in my opinion. There's no noticeable change in performance either.

Comment: Enumerate seems to be overkill in this case. You don't even need the v variable, a clear indicator of overcomplication. A simple list comprehension gets the job done.

Comment: For the sake of looking better, I'd still vote for it. There's no noticeable difference in speed. A dummy variable is worth it. I guess it comes down to personal taste

Comment: inefficient in all the separate setitem's it requires.

Answer (score 0):

For value types such as int, bool and string, your 2nd example is about as pretty as its going to get.  Your first example will work on any reference types like classes, dicts, or other lists.

Comment: The first example will only "work" if you're not trying to change the item contained within the list. If you're doing for x in a: x.foo() then that's certainly okay. However, if a is a list of dicts then for x in a: x = {} does not do what is intended, for the same reason as the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
bool_list = [False for element in bool_list]
```

is as pythonic as it gets. Using lists like this should generaly be faster then a for loop in python too.

Comment: Why repeat a previous answer?  Why not upvote the other answer?  I'm not sure what's distinct about this answer.  Perhaps I'm missing something.  Could you revise or expand your answer to emphasize the unique information?