# Dictionary value is another dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Consider this

```
dict1={}
dict2={}
dict2["first_d2"]="Yes"
dict1["first_d1"]=dict2
print dict1
print dict2
dict2={}
print dict1      ===>Here's the doubt
print dict2
```

The Output:

```
{'first_d1': {'first_d2': 'Yes'}}
{'first_d2': 'Yes'}
{'first_d1': {'first_d2': 'Yes'}}   ===>Why is this not resetting?Its referencing to dict2
{}
```

Now python dictionaries are mutable.So `dict1` is referencing to `dict2`.Now after first operation `dict2` is reset,why is the value of `dict1` not resetting?

As per my understanding mutable object change the contents in memory and do not return a new object.So why is this not happening here?What am i missing?

I am confused from the point of view of mutable and immutable!

Comment: Already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/369898/difference-between-dict-clear-and-assigning-in-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712256/programming-basic-python-assignment/30712592#30712592)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dict2 = {}
```

The above line only make the variable `dict2` reference new variable, not the item in the `dict1['first_d1']`.

If you want to change both (clear all entries in `dict2` dictionary), use [`dict.clear`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.clear) method:

```
dict2.clear()
```

In addition to this further info can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30712592/3679490)

Comment: @vks, `dict1['first_d1']` reference the dict object the `dict2` reference, not `dict2` variable itself.

Comment: @vks, `dict2 = {}` does not change the object `dict2` reference, but make a new dictionary and make the variable `dict2` reference the new dictionary.

Comment: @vks, Try to print the id of the dictionary object `id(dict2)` before and after `dict2 = {}` statement run.

Comment: @vks, Any immutable / mutable object can be reassigned. `dict.clear()` method is there to mutate the dictionary.

Comment: @vks, I hope this screenshot help delivering what I mean. http://i.imgur.com/gE6d2w9.png

Comment: Just added a link which had more detailed answer.Hope u dont mind.Thanx a lot for answering my querries and `id` part did add to it.